# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory'

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

Iam working with spring , hibernate maven project am getting the exception Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory'  on dispatcher servlet.xml file.  Below iam adding the three file contents. both dispatcherservlet and application context are in resources folder.
what is the problem? please help

My error:org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockBo' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'stockDao' while setting bean property 'stockDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockDao' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined

Dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<!-- Stock Data Access Object -->

<bean id="stockBo" lazy-init="true" class="com.org.rolltickets.stock.bo.impl.StockBoImpl" >
<property name="stockDao">
<ref local="stockDao" />
</property>
</bean>


 <bean id="stockDao" lazy-init="true" class="com.org.rolltickets.stock.dao.impl.StockDaoImpl" >
<property name="sessionFactory">
<ref bean="sessionFactory" />
</property>
</bean>
```

Applcaitioncontext.xml

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/hibernate/Stock.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Web.xml file

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Is your xml file actually called ApplicationContext.xml, or is it Applcaitioncontext.xml. The name has to match in your web.xml file or its not going to work.

Comment: No that was a mistake in my question only. I used the exact name to include in web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your config inside your dispatcher-servlet.xml into another xml file called root-servlet.xml (the name doesn't actually matter, what matters is that you move it to a new file).

Leave the dispatcher-servlet.xml file blank.

Then inside your web.xml add the new XML file after you list your ApplicationContext.xml

It should look like this:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    <param-value>classpath:root-servlet.xml</param-value> 
 <context-param>
```

What is happening, is that the servlet is running the code inside your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` before its running your `ApplicationContext.xml` file.

So the `dataSource` bean doesn't exist yet. By running ApplciationContext.xml first, you will create the bean, so it will be available.

Comment: I have done this with this solution , but it doesnt works for me . The issue is what you said may right. When i move the entire  beans from dispatcher-servlet to application context it works.  What will be the problem?

Comment: when i add <import resource="classpath:ApplicationContext.xml"/> in dispatcher-servlet.xml it works. But is that requirement?